# Why are the dates of some files and folders of a bootable USB running Ubuntu different than the compilation date?

Tags: live-usb, compiling, iso

I am running Ubuntu from a Bootable USB, and I see many folder and files with the date August 5th, I will refer to this date as the compilation date. But I also see a few files that have other dates, and I am wondering if excluding the date in which I am running this instance, why are there files and folders with dates that are different than the compilation and running date?

For example, the image below shows a list of files and directories. Most of these have a date of August 5, I began running this Ubuntu instance on February 12, but I see some files with different dates, and in the image below, I point these out with the green arrows:

[Image of Ubuntu's etc directory contents that points out files and directories that have a last touch date different than compilation and running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsm0x.png)

I expected all files to have either the compilation or the running date.

How do the dates of files and folders is stored when an ISO is compiled? Do files and folders keep their dates of last touch and the compilation date has no effect on these?

Comment: You are looking at the folder `/etc` which stands for editable text configuration. These are text files with configuration information. They are not compiled.